# How to change colour based on selection?

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

I was wondering how to change the image being displayed to a specific colour when it is selected?

I tried changing the labels but that didn't work out. Is there some settings in the system that I have to change?

Answer (score 0):

Magento doesn't provide any functionality to change images based on color. For his you can use third party extension.

I have used below Amasty extension for my requirement. I hope it will work for you.

[Color Swatches](https://amasty.com/color-swatches-pro.html)

Comment: This is not true, since Magento 1.9 you can use color swatches for that: http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-configurable-swatch.html

Comment: @mizuti Thanks, I didn't checked this new feature of magento.